# What is the recommended way of passing parameters in Django request when its required in each request?

Tags: python, django, django-views, request, django-request

I have to pass two parameters in every Django Request to use them in a decorator which is being called on every view of my Django application.

Currently, I am using the following way to pass parameters.

```py
class RoleTaskForm(forms.Form):
    task_id = forms.CharField(max_length=256, required=False)
    action = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=False)
```

Using following form in html documents

```html
<form name="role_task_form" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="task_id">
        <input type="hidden" name="operation">
</form>
```

Following JS function to manipulate the form values i.e. to change the action of form accordingly and set parameter values.

```js
function editProfile() {
    let form = document.role_task_form;
    form.task_id.value = "ProfileManagement";
    form.operation.value = 'edit';
    form.action = '/myschoolspace/edit-profile';
    form.submit();
}
```

And call above JS function to the anchor tags of HTML pages from where we have to navigate to the views.

I am using this method to pass parameters to every request, but I feel this is not a best practice when Its necessary to pass parameters in each request.

Kindly recommend me the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set of common decorators and use that in several places, you can define a list or tuple of decorators and use this instead of invoking method_decorator() multiple times. These two classes are equivalent:

```
decorators = [never_cache, login_required]
@method_decorator(decorators, name='dispatch')
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#id1)

Comment: Actually my question was about the best practice of passing parameters in the request